# EntityFramework 5 and Repositories

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I am learning EF 5 and am trying to understand the reason for passing a repository from the main window (load point) into a View Model.

I have read that the best way to use `context` is via the using `block` like so:

```
        // within CompanyViewModel
        using (var _context = new MyEntities())
        {
            var _query = from co in _context.Companies
                         select co;
            this.AllCompanies = new ObservableCollection<Models.Company>(_query);

        }
```

where `MyEntities` is the object created by VS in the EDMX file.

So my question is if I can simply call MyEntities from a ViewModel, why would I pass a repository (a reference to `MyEntities`) into each ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes your code inherently more testable by separating the code that interacts with your database from the code that drives the client side part of your application.

See the posts [here](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363501/Repository-pattern-with-Entity-Framework-Code-Firs) for more explanation as to the repository pattern and its general uses.